# Different encoding from file and from str ( \n \n\r ) - Solved

Tags: python, string, api, encode, vk

I read file in python and then send one string with vk_api

```
 with open('vk_posts.txt', 'r') as f:
     post_list = [x for x in f.readlines()]
     f.close()

 strmsg = post_list_python[0]
 vk.wall.post(message=strmsg)
```

it's working great except messages with multilines
if i read string from file like  "1\n2\r\n3" result look like

```
"1\n2\r\n3"
```

but if i change code

```
vk.wall.post(message="1\n2\r\n3")
```

result will change to

```
1
2
3
```

I need same result but with reading string from file.

Thanks!

========================================
My solution:

```
strmsg = strmsg.replace(r"\n", "\n")
```

Comment: Does the file contain actual linefeed and carriage return characters, or the literal digraphs `\n` and `\r`?

Comment: file contain plain text, all \n and \r just text

Comment: If you think your question was worth asking and you have an answer for it, it is recommended to provide an answer to your own question, so that it appears as answered, and so that others can easily find the answer when they encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your file doens't have newlines, it has literal `\` and `n` characters, which are called escape codes.

Give a file with this literal content:

```
1\n2\r\n3
```

You can open the file and decode it with:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:  # default open does not translate escape codes.
...  print(f.read())
...
1\n2\r\n3
>>> with open('test.txt',encoding='unicode_escape') as f:
...  print(f.read())
...
1
2
3
```

Note, though, that the `unicode_escape` codec only allows `latin1`-encoded characters along with escape codes in the file, so if your file contains non-ASCII characters that aren't members of the [latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set, you'll still have an issue.

Comment: it's not working for me, maybe because i use russian language, i found another solution : message.replace(r"\n", "\n")

Comment: @Dmitry_scraping Yes, Russian isn't part of the `latin1` character set.  You should update your question with more detail and a true example of your file.  Do you know the encoding of the data as well?  UTF-8 or some Russian-specific encoding?